# Equivariant splitting of loop space of a suspension

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, equivariant-homotopy

It is well known, e.g. by Cohen's "A model for the free loop space of a suspension", that there is a stable splitting of the free loop space $\mathcal{L} 
\Sigma X $of the  suspension $\Sigma X $ given by

$$
\Sigma^{\infty} \mathcal{L} X \simeq \bigoplus_{n>1} \Sigma^{\infty}(S^1_+ \wedge_{C_n} X^n)
$$

where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, and $S^1_+ \wedge_{C_n} X^n$ is the $S^1$-space induced by the inclusion of groups $C_n \to S^1$ and viewing  $X^n$ as a $C_n$-space.

I would like to know if this can be promoted to an $S^1$-equivariant splitting, at least in the case when $X$ is an $k$-sphere. There seems to be some equivariance going on, as the map is induced by a map (at the level of spaces)

$$
X^n \to \mathcal{L}X
$$

which is equivariant with respect to the $C_n$-action on the left, and the $C_n$-action on the right obtained by restricting the $S^1$ action. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The following article, which you probably have seen, might be related https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374740